# Getting Tomcat to Serve up pages in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat

I'm able to run local host and see the Apache Tomcat congratulations screen. In Eclipse I have a src/main/webapp/index.jsp file. When I start up my server I want to see this page, but it just displays the default Tomcat page. How do I get Tomcat to serve up my Eclipse files rather than the default page in Tomcat? Thank you.

Comment: Are you deploying your app to the root context in Tomcat? If not, you can probably already view your page just by going to the right path.

Comment: Does the Java workspace have to be somewhere inside the apache-tomcat directory?

Comment: Exactly how are you launching Tomcat from within Eclipse?

Comment: Just right clicking on the project and selecting Run as -> Run on Server.  LocalHost serves the pages from a folder called webapps. My web app is deployed to a folder called wtpwebapps. localhost:8080 serves the pages in the webapps folder. How can I get it to serve the pages in my wtpwebapps folder? wtpwebapps and webapps are in the same directory.

Comment: Ok it's working now and I don't know why. Perhaps restarting eclipse made it work? It's so annoying when something starts to work and you don't know why.